# Chi-Square analysis after ANOVA and correlations failed to give results

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test

I have a continuous dependent variable and two independent grouping variables of age and gender. Age has three groups and gender two (obviously!). Now ANOVA has shown no differences across both. However, DV has 25 questions which can be responded in Yes/No format, giving a score of 1 for Yes and 0 for No. I am planning to use Chi-square analysis to see the differences in frequency for each question. N=90, so I am expecting on some questions males would have scored more than females which can be known through chi-square, but due to total scores on DV for 25 questions such differences are not apparent. When I did the analysis, I got to see differences on 2 questions for gender and 2 for age groups too.

I want to know whether this would be a valid way to report the results or do we have to stop at ANOVA because I have not seen such analyses reported previously in my literature. When I did the similar analysis on other DVs, I found contrasting results. On a DV2, which was significant for age groups differences, out of 25 questions, I found differences on only 3 through chi-square. It seems that ANOVA biases the results for whole pool of items while chi-square analysis is more clear.